# Even though http-server and angular-http-server installed, get "bash: http-server: command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, npm, debian

[image]I tried use the current ways around stackoverflow but still get `bash: http-server: command not found`

also th **npm list -g http-server** returns:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/local/lib/node_modules $ npm list -g http-server
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)
```

and the **echo $PATH** returns followed result based on **.bashrc** file:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/usr/.npm-global/bin:/usr/.npm-global/bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Additionaly I install it with this command `sudo npm install http-serve -g`  which can see its output as below:

```
/root/.npm-global/bin/http-serve -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-serve/bin/http-serve
/root/.npm-global/bin/hs -> /root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-serve/bin/http-serve
+ http-serve@1.0.1
added 21 packages from 25 contributors in 13.863s
```

Comment: You're installing `http-serve` and calling `http-server` commands

Comment: sorry it is typo, same result with `sudo npm install http-server -g` and `sudo npm install -g angular-http-server`

Comment: Run `find / -name "*http*server*" -print` to find where the file is.  Then add the directory to your `$PATH` variable, and try again.  If the file is not there, then it is not installed, or not using the filename you are expecting.  If you know where it is, try starting it with the complete path.  If that works, again add the directory to your $PATH variable.

Comment: Thanks @Nic3500 it returns `/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-server
/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-server/lib/http-server.js
/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server
/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-server/doc/http-server.1
/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/angular-http-server
/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/angular-http-server/lib/angular-http-server.js
/root/.npm-global/share/man/man1/http-server.1
/root/.npm-global/bin/http-server
/root/.npm-global/bin/angular-http-server /usr/local/bin/http-server
`which my path includes all of them

Comment: Indeed...  Are you able to start is if you specify the full path (`/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-server` ?  I.E. do you have the permissions for it?  I know of at least 1 unix flavor where if the permissions are not ok, it will say the file does not exist even if it does.

Comment: @Nic3500 I did `export PATH="$PATH:/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-server"
` and remove and install http-server again and still same error. additionally i switched to root user and did same process but no result

Comment: ok, but can you run `/root/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/http-server`?  If that does not work, then it is not a $PATH issue...

Comment: it desnt and still returns command not found

Answer (score 1):

Switch to your current user by using '-'. This way all the references will be copied. Usually, this error is also given when references are missing.

Also, try to give the full path of the command.